# Dynamic library in main ios app target builds with no symbols, when debugging the widget extension

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, linker, widget

I have a SwiftUI iOS app with widget extension. I have extracted a common code into a framework, and have set it to build as a dynamic library. The framework is embedded (embed & sign) in the main app target, and linked from the widget extension.

I found out that when I create a scheme to run the widget extension in simulator, the widget runs fine, but opening the main app in the same simulator fails immediately with a crash, as the app cannot find any symbol from the common code framework.

I have navigated to the build folder, ran `nm ./Frameworks/CommonKit.framework/CommonKit`, and it shows zero symbols (and also the framework binary is tiny, about 34 kB - it definitely doesn't have all the code it should have).

It seems that:

1. If I debug the widget extension, the main app crashes as it cannot find any symbols from the shared library
2. And when I debug the main app, the widget extension crashes as it cannot find any symbols from the shared library

Here is the whole crash:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: DYLD 4 Symbol missing
Symbol not found: _$s10Foundation4DateV15CommonKitE11AddTomorrowOMa
Referenced from: <3D5A4B08-B980-3098-9BB5-1469DC662631> /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/635C1833-95B7-421A-8720-C367E6D564D1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/0D9AB3ED-BBCE-4E7B-98D6-9515081770C9/MyApp.app/MyApp
Expected in:     <E0A56B44-D392-3EC8-9336-750BD5303843> /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/635C1833-95B7-421A-8720-C367E6D564D1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/0D9AB3ED-BBCE-4E7B-98D6-9515081770C9/MyApp.app/Frameworks/CommonKit.framework/CommonKit
(terminated at launch; ignore backtrace)
```

Runpath search path seems to be set ok (`@executable_path/Frameworks` and `@executable_path/../../Frameworks` for extensions), so it seems that the extension finds the framework well, only it finds it empty.

When I build the whole app (= main app + extension) for device, it works, and when I set the library to static library, the crashes stop (but then it is compiled into both app targets, increasing the app size, so I'd prefer the dynamic library).

What can be the cause?

Comment: It seems that setting `Create merged binary = NO` for the main app prevents the crash, but this seems more like the Xcode 15's merging is the culprit?